# Beautiful Soup tag inside tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add a new link as an unordered list element.

But I can't add a tag inside another with Beautiful Soup.

```
with open('index.html') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

a = soup.select_one("id[class=pr]")
ntag1 = soup.new_tag("a", href="hm/test")
ntag1.string = 'TEST'
... (part with problem)
a.insert_after(ntag2)
```

ntag1 must stay inside `"<li>"`, so I tried

```
   ntag2 = ntag1.new_tag('li')  
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

with wrap()

```
 ntag2 = ntag1.wrap('li')
   ValueError: Cannot replace one element with another when theelement to be replaced is not part of a tree.
```

Original HTML

```
<id class="pr">
    </id>
    <li>
     <a href="pr/protocol">
      protocol
     </a>
```

Desirable html output

```
<id class="pr">
</id>
<li>
 <a href="hm/test">
  TEST
 </a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="pr/protocol">
  protocol
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you get a `NoneType` error is because `ntag2 = ntag1.new_tag('li')` is trying to call a method the [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) object doesn't have.

The *`Cannot replace one element with another when theelement`* is from the fact you have created a tag that has no association to the tree, it has *no parent* which it must have if you are trying to *wrap*.

It would make more sense to create the *parent li* and just append the *anchor child*:

```
html = """<div class="pr">
</div>
<li>
 <a href="pr/protocol">
  protocol
 </a>
 </li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

a = soup.select_one("div[class=pr]")

# Li parent
parent = soup.new_tag("li", class_="parent")
# Child anchor
child = soup.new_tag("a", href="hm/test", class_="child")
child.string = 'TEST'
# Append child to parent
parent.append(child)
# Insert parent
a.insert_after(parent)
print(soup.prettify())
```

which would give you the output you want bar the html not being valid.

If you have an actual ul you want to get to after a certain element, i.e.

```
html = """<div class="pr">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="pr/protocol">
          protocol
          </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
     """
```

Set a's css selector to `div[class=pr] + ul"` and insert the parent:

```
a = soup.select_one("div[class=pr] + ul")
.....
a.insert(0, parent)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Which would give you:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="pr">
  </div>
  <ul>
   <li class_="parent">
    <a class_="child" href="hm/test">
     TEST
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="pr/protocol">
     protocol
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Of if you wanted to *wrap* one existing tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

html = """<div class="pr">
    </div>
     <a href="pr/protocol">
          protocol
     """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

a = soup.select_one("div[class=pr] + a")
a.wrap(Tag(name="div"))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Which would wrap the existing anchor:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="pr">
  </div>
  <div>
   <a href="pr/protocol">
    protocol
   </a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```